# how to get the frequency of unique elements in a column of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have a dataframe:

```
 X65L X65L.1 X65L.2   X67L X67L.1 X65L.3
 [1,] 0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
 [2,] 0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
 [3,] 0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
 [4,] 0.0065 0.0067 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
 [5,] 0.0065 0.0067 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
 [6,] 0.0065 0.0067 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
 [7,] 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067
 [8,] 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067
 [9,] 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0071
[10,] 0.0067 0.0084 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0071
[11,] 0.0067 0.0084 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084
[12,] 0.0067 0.0084 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084
```

I want to count the frequency of each unique element in a column and get an output like this:

```
     6     3     6     0     0     6
     6     3     6    12     6     2
     0     3     0     0     3     2
     0     3     0     0     3     2
```

The MATLAB equivalent is:

```
[m1 n1]=hist(s,unique(s));
```

I would like to know, how this could be done in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
apply(mat, 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique(c(mat)))))
```

which gives

```
       X65L X65L.1 X65L.2 X67L X67L.1 X65L.3
0.0065    6      3      6    0      0      6
0.0067    6      3      6   12      6      2
0.0071    0      3      0    0      3      2
0.0084    0      3      0    0      3      2
```

**Data**

```
> dput(mat)
structure(c(0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0067, 
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065,
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0071, 0.0071, 0.0071, 0.0084, 0.0084,
0.0084, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0067,
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067,
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0071,
0.0071, 0.0071, 0.0084, 0.0084, 0.0084, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065,
0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0071, 0.0071, 0.0084,
0.0084), .Dim = c(12L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X65L",
"X65L.1", "X65L.2", "X67L", "X67L.1", "X65L.3")))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain the desired output we need to fill in 0 whenever we don't have certain values within a column:

**Code**

```
# First obtain all possible values
name <- levels(as.factor(unlist(df)))
tmp1 <- rep(0, length(name))
names(tmp1) <- name

tmp1
# 0.0065 0.0067 0.0071 0.0084 
#      0      0      0      0 

# Now fill this table whenever we have additional information within a column

sapply(df, function(x){
  tmp1[names(table(x))] <- table(x) 
  tmp1
})

#        X65L X65L.1 X65L.2 X67L X67L.1 X65L.3
# 0.0065    6      3      6    6      6      6
# 0.0067    6      3      6   12      6      2
# 0.0071    0      3      0    0      3      2
# 0.0084    0      3      0    0      3      2
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "X65L X65L.1 X65L.2   X67L X67L.1 X65L.3
0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
0.0065 0.0067 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
0.0065 0.0067 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
0.0065 0.0067 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067
0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067
0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0071
0.0067 0.0084 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0071
0.0067 0.0084 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084
0.0067 0.0084 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

`table()` does that function for a vector. You can use `apply()` to run this function for every column. `apply(data.frame,2,table)`. Results may be presented as a list, tough, if the values are different between the columns.

Comment: This is what the output is:
$X65L

0.0065 0.0067 
     6      6 

$X65L.1

0.0065 0.0067 0.0071 0.0084 
     3      3      3      3 

$X65L.2

0.0065 0.0067 
     6      6 

$X67L

0.0067 
    12 

$X67L.1

0.0067 0.0071 0.0084 
     6      3      3 

$X65L.3

0.0065 0.0067 0.0071 0.0084 
     6      2      2      2 

I want a data frame out of it with 0 for the elements it doesn't have just like shown in the question

Answer (score 0):

We could also do this with

```
table(c(mat), colnames(mat)[col(mat)])
```

-output

```
#           X65L X65L.1 X65L.2 X65L.3 X67L X67L.1
#  0.0065    6      3      6      6    0      0
#  0.0067    6      3      6      2   12      6
#  0.0071    0      3      0      2    0      3
#  0.0084    0      3      0      2    0      3
```

#### data

```
mat <- structure(c(0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0067, 
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065,
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0071, 0.0071, 0.0071, 0.0084, 0.0084,
0.0084, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0067,
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067,
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0071,
0.0071, 0.0071, 0.0084, 0.0084, 0.0084, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065,
0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0071, 0.0071, 0.0084,
0.0084), .Dim = c(12L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X65L",
"X65L.1", "X65L.2", "X67L", "X67L.1", "X65L.3")))
```

Comment: What a brilliant solution! Learned from you always! Liked it +1!